# Order foreach XML loop & ignore results

Tags: php, html, xml, simplexml

I want to Order my list by the "Order" field and check the date one the "date" field, if the date is later then today (tomorrow) then i need it to skip it.

Here is the code i have

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("db.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
$i=0;
foreach($xml->children() as $book) 
{ 
echo $book->title . ", "; 
        echo $book->date . ", "; 
        echo $book->link . ", ";
        echo $book->order . ", ";
        echo $book->show . ", ";
        $i++;
        if($i == 4) {
        echo "<br>";
        $i=0;
        }

}
```

I tried using the asorte() option but only ended up with an error...Probably something i was doing wrong though....

Thanks for the help!

Comment: There's no `asorte` function, unless you wrote it by yourself.

Comment: @u_mulder take a look at this http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php

Comment: `asort` not a `asorte`.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/33703064/2016456